# magento https not format css

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, https

Good afternoon everybody, I'm facing a big problem. I've tried all the possibilities (or not), and HTTPS he loses all settings ...

see: magiadasjoias.com.br

I cleared cache, tested in different browsers, called and hung Rewriting (SEO) and nothing!

I did so: Rewriting with On and Off

https ://web929.uni5.net/~magiadasjoias/index.php/

{{}} secure_base_url

secure_base_url {{}} skin /

{{}} secure_base_url media /

secure_base_url {{}} js /

Where can I be missing?

If anyone can help me thank you very much!

updating for today 11/09

Until then I was with the base of magento installed in the SHOP, and now I migrated everything to the root of the problem remains exactly the same ...

Loading is thus, for example:
https://web929.uni5.net/~magiadasjoias/index.php/customer/account/login/

using the base:

https: //web929.uni5.net/~magiadasjoias/**index.php**/

or

https: //web929.uni5.net/~magiadasjoias/

Is it something related to permission Folders? I looked and they are all with 777.

If anyone can help me thank you very much.

Comment: All of your scripts are throwing 404 errors. They're looking for the css and js scripts in https://web929.uni5.net/~magiadasjoias/index.php/skin/frontend/default/ma_sportshop/ . You probably need to check your theme settings.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, sometimes the `base_url` variables are cached on the database level, since they are requested so often on the frontend.

Try doing the following:

1. Go to **System > Configuration > Web**
2. Under the **Unsecure** section, replace all instances of `{{unsecure_base_url}}` to your unsecure base url value, like: `http://yourwebsite.com/`
3. Under the **Secure** section, replace all instances of `{{secure_base_url}}` to your secure base url value, like: `https://yourwebsite.com/`
4. Save your configuration, and clear all Magento caches.

Also, your permissions set should be **755** for folders.  Using **777** can leave your filesytem vulnerable to public attacks.

If you have access to shell, the following command will set all files/folder to the correct permissions:

```
chmod -R 755 *; find -type f -print0|xargs -0 chmod 644
```

Comment: does anybody knows where the  `base_url` is cached , or how to purge this cache?

Comment: Under System > Cache Management.  Refresh the caches there for configuration caches.

Comment: Also if you dont have access to admin panel or you are on the CLI you can remove everyting under `magento_root_dir/var/cache/*` with posible undesired side effects